# How to import an Axis2 sample project into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache, import, apache-axis, sample

How to import an Apache Axis2 sample project into eclipse ? I tried to import the project named pojo, but no success.. What folder to import??? It seems that normal importing method doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dynamic web project in Eclipse (You need to have Eclipse J2EE version)

[image: Create new dynamic web project]

Copy the sample pojo source code from the AXIS2_HOME\sample directory to the dynamic web project source code directory

[image: AXIS2_HOME\Sample\pojo]

[image: Copy POJO source to the dynamic web source]

Create a new Webservice from Eclipse

[image]

Select Bottom Up and Select the AddressBookService in the package sample.addressbook.service

Make sure you select Axis, and the Project name. Also check the Client options as below,

[image]

Click Finish

[image]

Move the client code to the client project PojoClient (AddressBookADBClient in package sample.addressbook.adbclient

[image]

Refactor the package name and methods to fit the stub automatically generated

I have made 3 changes
Modified the package name to match the stubs

```
1) //import sample.addressbook.stub.AddressBookServiceStub;
import sample.addressbook.service.AddressBookServiceStub;
```

Modified the method name to match the stubs

```
2)//addEntry.setArgs0(entry);
   addEntry.setEntry(entry);
```

Modified the method name to match the stubs

```
3) //findEntry.setArgs0("Abby Cadabby");
    findEntry.setName("Abby Cadabby");
```

[image]

One final change in the service, since i was not able to get the test it.
I made the entries variable to static
 private static HashMap entries = new HashMap();

[image]

All Set response from SOAP UI

[image]

[image]

Response from Client Java Code

[image]